# How to use NtOpenProcess

Tags: winapi, ntdll

I am trying to use `NtOpenProcess()` I have not find any example in town.

I am getting an error any help is much appreciated.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int showCmd)
{
    HANDLE handle;
    HWND myWindow =FindWindow(NULL, L"Notepad");
    PCLIENT_ID PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(myWindow, (LPDWORD)&PID);
    ZwOpenProcess(&handle, PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, NULL,PID);
    return 0;
}
```

The errors are

```
1>c:\users\asus\source\repos\windowsproject2\windowsproject2\windowsproject2.cpp(14): error C2065: 'PCLIENT_ID': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\asus\source\repos\windowsproject2\windowsproject2\windowsproject2.cpp(14): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'PID'
1>c:\users\asus\source\repos\windowsproject2\windowsproject2\windowsproject2.cpp(14): error C3861: 'NtOpenProcess': identifier not found
1>c:\users\asus\source\repos\windowsproject2\windowsproject2\windowsproject2.cpp(14): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'PID'
1>c:\users\asus\source\repos\windowsproject2\windowsproject2\windowsproject2.cpp(14): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

This are my include files.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <Ntifs.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-ntopenprocess)

Comment: @MichaelWalz the documentation is unclear to me. Any example is much appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes. I include them after `Windows.h`

Comment: Try to put  `#include "stdafx.h"` _before_ `#include <Windows.h>`, or put `# include <Windows.h> #include <ntddk.h>
#include <Ntifs.h>` into `stdafx.h`

Comment: @MichaelWalz it shows `ntdef.h` error. Sorry to disturb you I am currently learning Win32.

Comment: If you are learning Win32, then `NtOpenProcess` is probably not the thing to start with.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I already know pointers and reference variable. I am just trying this sample function I just need an example to point me to the right path.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I use `GetWindowThreadProcessId(myWindow, &PID);` to find my PID.

Comment: Short answer: use `OpenProcess` instead of `NtOpenProcess` or `ZwOpenProcess`. Question: what are you trying to achieve?  Read this: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't want `OpenProcess` I want it to the lowest level of the function. I want it to be undetectable by going to the lowest level. It is detectable using `OpenProcess` they are hooking `OpenProcess` then blocks it. I want it to be undetectable using `NtOpenProcess` sir.

Comment: `PCLIENT_ID PID; GetWindowThreadProcessId(myWindow, (LPDWORD)&PID);` - this is wrong and senseless

Comment: @RbMm sorry perharps you can show how to use it.

Comment: `NtOpenProcess` isn't part of the Windows API. If you want to learn the Windows API, go with `OpenProcess`. If you want to learn about the Native API, don't ask for help with the Windows API. If you intend to [become a system security analyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985844/how-to-use-ntopenprocess#comment84979422_48987318), prepare to invest a decade up front. If your top tag is [tag:java], set aside another year or two to unlearn the bad.

Comment: Besides, [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) is documented to accept a `DWORD*`. Passing random types based on (poor) guessing isn't going to get you far. Plus, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-ntopenprocess) explicitly states: *"If the call to this function occurs in user mode, you should use the name `NtOpenProcess` instead of `ZwOpenProcess`."* Why are you ignoring the documentation?

Comment: You are deeply confused. If OpenProcess can be hooked, so can NtOpenProcess. You are out of your depth.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan its not really getting hooked by some protector. The NtOpenProcess

Comment: So your goal is to defeat rubbish malware, you are happy to lose to half way competent malware?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you have some books? About NtOpenProcess I would really love to read one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just really hates this unclear documentation of websites.

Comment: We can't give out recommendations here. Remember that the native API is not documented, so you should not expect any documentation of it.

Answer (score 1):

at first look at code:

```
FindWindow(NULL, L"Notepad");
```

faster of all you want

```
FindWindow(L"Notepad", 0);
```

because L"Notepad" is class name (not window name) and class name first parameter.

```
PCLIENT_ID PID;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(myWindow, (LPDWORD)&PID);
```

the `GetWindowThreadProcessId` wait pointer to `DWORD` memory, where it store process id. but you pass to it uninitialized pointer, to random memory. need use this:

```
CLIENT_ID pid = { };
if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(myWindow, (PDWORD)&pid.UniqueProcess))
```

finally `ObjectAttributes` in call `NtOpenProcess` is mandatory parameter and can not be 0.

about undeclared identifiers - all this declared in `ntifs.h` and it sub-headers (`ntifs.h` include `ntddk.k` - so you not need include it direct). problem that `windows.h` and `ntifs.h` is conflict - many common declarations. if you include both - you got a lot of errors. but solution exist - include `ntifs.h` in some namespace. but even after this you got some errors. but this also can be fixed, if deep understand source of errors. also you will be need include own code to this namespace too, for have easy access to ntifs declarations. and finally you need use `ntdll.lib` or `ntdllp.lib` (will be conflict with CRT libs if you use it) as linker input.

so if you want use native api in own code, without add custom headers, where you copy-paste some nt definitions and call it without resolve api in runtime, but use static linking - this is possible, but require deep knowledge and understanding what you doing. example

```
#define DECLSPEC_DEPRECATED_DDK

#define _XX_BEGIN   namespace XX {
#define _XX_END     }

_XX_BEGIN

struct _SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE;
struct _CONTEXT;

_XX_END

#define _INC_MMSYSTEM  /* Prevent inclusion of mmsystem.h in windows.h */
#include <windows.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4005)

_XX_BEGIN

#ifdef _RTL_RUN_ONCE_DEF
#undef _RTL_RUN_ONCE_DEF
#endif

#define RtlCompareMemory ::RtlCompareMemory

#include <ntifs.h>

_XX_END

#undef _INC_MMSYSTEM  /* Prevent inclusion of mmsystem.h in windows.h */
#include <MMSystem.h>

_XX_BEGIN

void demo()
{
    if (HWND myWindow = FindWindow(L"Notepad", 0))
    {
        CLIENT_ID pid = { };
        if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(myWindow, (PDWORD)&pid.UniqueProcess))
        {
            HANDLE handle;
            static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa) };
            if (0 <= NtOpenProcess(&handle, 
                PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, 
                &zoa, &pid))
            {
                NtClose(handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
_XX_END
```

Comment: can you suggest a good book about ntdll programming. I really want to learn Win32 I want to become a system security analyst.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will just try to read c and get back on this. The book says I need to learn c first to understand the #define #ifndef #undef