# Error checking and formating for Win32 and NTSATUS error codes like for HRESULTS?

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

When dealing with COM, `FAILED` and `SUCCEEDED` macros help us check if error.
and to format `HRESULT` into a string `_com_error` object can be used.

Is there an equivalent for `NTSTATUS` and `Win32` errors codes? such as macros or functions which will tell if error code indicates an error or success and an `API` to format them into a string.

I know we can format `Win32` error message with `FormatMessage` API but I just need to check if an error code indicates an error in first place before formating.

Also second related question for completness is dealing with `NTSTATUS` error codes, how do we format `NTSTATUS` into string message and how to check if `NTSTATUS` code is error or success?

I know there is error handling library proved by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil/wiki/Error-handling-helpers) but these headers doesn't seem to offer formating errors into a string nor do they offer to check error vs success status. but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: with `NTSTATUS` all is very simply - 2 highest bit is say about this - look [*Using NTSTATUS Values*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values), and for format string - call `FormatMessage` with `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` flag and `GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll")`.

Comment: for win32 - any value other than 0 - is error, here no general additional information. usual win32 errors is created from initial `NTSATUS` with frequently loss information

Comment: with `NTSTATUS status` value in most case need signed compare with 0. `0 > status` mean that call fail and `0 <= status` that success. of course this is in general.

Comment: This are great inputs, already reading MS site. although including `<ntdef.h>` which is needed to resolve status macros and codes results in lot's of errors and redefinitions. header mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values

Comment: you need include it in `namespace` for avoid errors. and you can simply copy macros. in general how i say - compare `status` with 0 for <= and >. but what is your target goal ? from where you got ntstatus ?

Comment: I'm including the `<ntstatus.h>` and `<ntdef.h>` from Windows SDK, in Visual Studio, I'm working on custom error checking library, otherwise I don't need NTSTATUS checking. just Win32 and HRESULTS. NTSTAUS looks like it's used for driver programming only?

Comment: *NTSTAUS looks like it's used for driver programming only?* - no of course. in user mode too and very wide

Comment: Is including these NT headers possible only with hackery such as including into namespace or is there conventional or should I say normal way? if ntstatus is used for user mode then there should be a way to include them togetehr with Windows.h without conflicts

Comment: my way - include *ntifs.h* in namespace. without *namespace* will be conflict with *windows.h*. but even after you include it in namespace - need some additional several lines of tricks. and in latest c++20 builds need off `/permissive-` option. so exist problems. [*example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987318/6401656) how include. also say Lsa wide use NTSTATUS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsantstatustowinerror

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the input!